# How does TailwindCSS achieve the breakpoint prefix functionality?

Tags: css, responsive, breakpoints, tailwind-css

within TailwindCSS you can specify such code:

```
<div class="bg-red-500 sm:bg-green-500 md:bg-blue-500></div>
```

So that the default color will be red, at the "sm" breakpoint it will be green and at the "md" breakpoint it will be blue.

You can assign any uitlity class to any breakpoint by prefixing it with the coresponding letters and a ":".

Does TailwindCSS simply generate every single utility class for/within every defined breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

Yes, it generates everything as defined per the tailwind config file.

**Longer answer**

It generates all the classes as per the config. This is to make your development life easier, so you don't have to worry about which classes are defined and which aren't.
Now you probably don't want all of the classes tailwind provides in production environment, only the ones which you actually use. If you want to know more about how to control the file size and removing unused css, read the [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/controlling-file-size/).